# Since Linux command cd could not be used as external command, is it possible to write my version of cd (which is not a shell-builtin command)?

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system

I am quite curious about that implementation, maybe refers to some low-level details, but I'd love to learn.

BTW, I am still looking for solution for the cd dilemma without rewriting that command. If you have any neat solution for that, please feel free to post here.

Comment: The problem is this: if `cd` is an external command, the shell will spawn a new process, invoke *your* cd which changes the pwd, and then the process exits. The changed directory disappears with the process and the shell remains in the same pwd. There's no way for a side effect of the spawned process to affect the parent shell process. It's not really a dilemma: `cd` **has** to be a shell builtin command.

Comment: What practical problem are you trying to solve? Does a `chroot` help?

Comment: On Solaris 9, there actually is a `/usr/bin/cd` external command. It doesn't change the current directory of the caller, but it can be used to test whether you *can* change to a given directory (for example `/usr/bin/cd /nosuchdir` fails). I'm not convinced it's useful, but it's there.

Comment: @KeithThompson: There's a `/usr/bin/cd` on Mac OS X too.  I think it exists to meet the requirements of POSIX.  `cd` is not one of the [special built-in utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), so it has to exist as a separate binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, you can't write your own `chdir` external command.

More precisely, you can, but it doesn't help you.  The trouble is that the change of directory made in the child process has no effect on the current directory of the parent process.  When the shell executes your external `chdir` command, the `chdir` command changes its own current directory but the shell that invoked it stays exactly where it was.

If you really, really wanted to do something, you could consider writing a `chdir` command that changed directory and then executed a shell in the new directory.  If you used:

```
exec chdir /some/where
```

then your original shell would be replaced with a new shell in a new current directory (`/some/where`).  But this would be fairly desperate measures.  Note that if you did not use `exec` as a prefix, each time you changed directory, you'd get a new shell.  It is a sort of directory stack, but you'd have to exit each shell in turn on the way out.  That would get very tiresome if you navigate around your file system very much.

---

#### `chdir.c`

This is a simple implementation of `chdir` command outlined in the answer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "so-stderr.h"

static char def_shell[] = "/bin/sh";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **cmdv;
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    if (argc <= 1)
        err_usage("directory [cmd [arg ...]]");
    if (chdir(argv[1]) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to change directory to %s\n", argv[1]);

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        static char *args[3] = { 0, "-i", (char *)0 };
        char *shell = getenv("SHELL");
        if (shell == 0)
            shell = def_shell;
        args[0] = shell;
        cmdv = args;
    }
    else
        cmdv = &argv[2];

    execvp(cmdv[0], cmdv);
    err_syserr("failed to execute %s\n", cmdv[0]);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
    return 0;
}
```

#### Error reporting

The only marginally complex part is using the error reporting functions from `so-stderr.h` and `so-stderr.c` because they're not standard. They're just functions that I wrote and that I use for error reporting in essentially all my programs.

The file names with the `so-` prefix are minimal versions (40-odd lines without comments) of a much more complex chunk of code with header `stderr.h` and source `stderr.c` (plus some auxilliary files, about 1000 lines with comments, which provides more complex interfaces in more functions, and more control generally).  Here's the vastly simplified (but fully functional) form of the functions used by the `chdir` program.

#### `so-stderr.c`

```
#include "so-stderr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char *argv0 = "**undefined**";

void err_setarg0(const char *arg0)
{
    argv0 = arg0;
}

void err_usage(const char *usestr)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s %s\n", argv0, usestr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void err_syserr(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", argv0);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "(%d: %s)", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    putc('\n', stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If I wanted to rely on C11, two of the three functions would be marked as `noreturn`.  It's another of the extra niceties supported in the main `stderr` package.

#### so-stderr.h

```
#ifndef SO_STDERR_H_INCLUDED
#define SO_STDERR_H_INCLUDED

extern void err_setarg0(const char *arg0);
extern void err_syserr(const char *fmt, ...);
extern void err_usage(const char *usestr);

#endif /* SO_STDERR_H_INCLUDED */
```

Comment: You could in theory write a shell script for `cd` and then source it with `period`. That would run in the same shell without spawning a process. I'm not saying it is ideal, but it would work lol

Comment: Well, I suppose so...it depends in part on your definition of 'external command'...but I recognize that your comment is mostly jocular.

Comment: I know ;-). The LOL on the end sorta indicates how I feel about the solution of using source ;-). You could create an alias for `cd` that would do the source of the new `cd` script.

Comment: @XupengTong: I'd use C, though you could prototype it more quickly, perhaps, in a script.  Define the command line interface: `chdir directory [command [arg …]]` would be what I'd use until I added options.  If no command is specified, run an (interactive) shell.  Then it is a straight-forward exercise in programming.  How would you do it?